# Dynamic Smart date mask while inserting date 

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Is there a way in javascript or jQuery to detect and change dynamically while typing a date for both a key input and a copy and paste to a text box?

I'm trying to create a functional text box which has two digits such as a month.

Since the month can be a number from 1 - 12 I want to enforce the first digit to be a 1 or a 0.

The trick that I'm trying to do however is when the text box first gains focus and a user beging to type a number, if that number is 2 - 9 I want a zero to automatically fill the first spot and then but the 9 in the second spot.

Before I type anything this date input would look like so:

```
__/__/_____
```

If I type a "1"

```
1_/__/_____
```

If I type "2" should get

```
02/__/_____
```

If I type "22" should get

```
02/2_/_____
```

If I type "77" should get

```
07/07/_____
```

I would be very interested for in an answer with code or a link to a tool that already does this or a link to a previous post?

Eventually I want to put it in a masked so 7/7/2011 or 7/7/11 or 07/07/2011 will alway fill to 07/07/2011.    In the final final version I am trying to get the year to default to the current decade but have a drop down to each 10 year++ --.

Comment: From an end user perspective, I find these types of things *extremely* effing annoying. This is only my opinion, of course. I would check the user experience stack exchange for advice on the best way to do these. They may have a full solution there already made.

Answer (score 2):

Why not attach a listener to the blur of the textbox, rather than to the user's typing.

Think about the user experience if you were typing "1", and all of a sudden, the input started adding or removing zeroes to what you were doing, while you were doing it?

```
var dayInput = document.getElementById("day-input");
// usually, I'd just use event-listeners, but feel free to refactor
dayInput.onblur = handleDayOrMonth;

function handleDayOrMonth () {
    var el = (this === window) ? event.srcElement : this,
        number_string = el.value;

    // checking that it's an actual number
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(number_string)) {
        if (number_string.length === 1) { el.value = "0" + number_string; }
    }
}
```

Handling the year would be just the same, except that you'd be adding "20" to the start of whatever it is.

Feel free to jQuery it up.

Comment: The users experience shouldn't be affected if the input is masked. <shrugg>

Comment: Yes.  The ideal experience, if you're going to that trouble, is to let the user input their values any way they'd like, and then format it into your expected result for the POST of the form, back to the server.

And the only times it should really coerce those formats is if: a) you aren't going to do hidden validation   or   b) it's a legitimate part of the experience (like padding 0s on a clock or a timer).

Comment: I like that idea.  I have seen an expanded view pop out sort of like "Zoomed out" that shows what they are typing at the same time showing how its auto magically formatting it in the zoomed out part.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the functionality that you want is provided by the [jQuery Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/SEXAj/

Please note that it also only allows numeric characters.

Comment: I'm already using this javascript and if you re-read the bounty's description the requirements should be clear.

Comment: I was able to bind on the keydown event.  Thanks for the jsfiddle.  I'm begrudgingly awarding you 50 pts.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't respond earlier, but I didn't have a better solution so there was no point in saying anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer goes here... jQuery [masked input plugin](http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/masked_input.php#nav-example).