# Date based function along with calculating fees

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me write a JavaScript Function that says if the date chosen is over 30 days from the current date then add $20 to my fee calculator? Any help would be greatly appreciated I am very new and not sure where to begin I cannot find any examples even similar..

This is the textbox/calendar:

```
<cfinput
       type="datefield"
       name="purchasedate"
       width="130"
       required="yes"
       message="Please enter purchase date."
       value="#dateformat(now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")#" 
       >
```

Radio Buttons deciding prices:

```
var title_prices = new Array();
 title_prices["MCO"]=78.25;
 title_prices["FL Title"]=78.25;
 title_prices["OOS Title"]=88.25;

function getProofOfOwnership()
{  
    var proofOfOwnership=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var ownerShip = theForm.elements["ownership"];
    for(var i = 0; i < ownerShip.length; i++)
    {
        if(ownerShip[i].checked)
        {
         proofOfOwnership = title_prices[ownerShip[i].value];
        }
    }    return proofOfOwnership;
}
```

This calls all functions and adds the fees together:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var titleFees = getProofOfOwnership() + (Function checking date);
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes a date parameter and returns 20 if the date is more than 30 days ago, or 0 if the date is within 30 days or in the future.

```
function getDatePrice(date) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) !== '[object Date]') {
        //If passed date is undefined or not valid, use today's date
        date = new Date();
    }

    var today = new Date();

    var diffMilli = today - date; 
    //Difference in milliseconds, need to convert to days
    var diffDays = diffMilli * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    if (diffDays > 30) {
        return 20;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Fiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rgjfwdpx/

Edit: To tie in to your code, you will need to retrieve the value from the `<cinput>` tag. I'm not familiar with them, but this is my quick guess on how to do it. It might not be right. Basically you need to get the text value from the input and then parse it into a new date.

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    //Get date from form. I've never worked with <cinput>, so this is just my guess
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var purchasedate = theForm.elements["purchasedate"];
    var date = new Date(purchasedate.value);

    var titleFees = getProofOfOwnership() + getDatePrice(date);
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}
```

Comment: The date param is the date that the user has selected that is compared to the current date. If no date is provided, the current date is used, which means it'll always return 0 of you don't pass in a date.

Comment: Is it possible to set the format for the date on that function as well?

Comment: What do you mean by set the format? Dates do not have a format by themselves, but when they're displayed they can be done so in different formats (yyyy-MM-dd, MM/dd/yyy, etc). There's no need to display the date in the above function, so no need to format it.

Comment: The issue is that I can not mask the textbox (datefield). The user can type anything they want in the box and submit.. 081085 .. 08102014 .. I want to make it where they can only type MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566560/dynamic-smart-date-mask-while-inserting-date

Comment: hmmm I reviewed it but I don't fully understand it =/